# NullPointerException in Salat

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

While making any type of call to Mongo from my Scala application, I am getting this NullPointerException. Can somebody please help.

I am using Mongo 3.0.1 and my Scala version is 2.9.0. Other dependencies are as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>casbah_2.9.1</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.novus</groupId>
    <artifactId>salat-core_2.9.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.morphia</groupId>
    <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
    <version>0.99</version>
</dependency>
```

Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.novus.salat.util.GraterPrettyPrinter$$anonfun$safeDefault$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PrettyPrinters.scala:74)

at com.novus.salat.util.GraterPrettyPrinter$$anonfun$safeDefault$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(PrettyPrinters.scala:74)

at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:134)

at com.novus.salat.util.GraterPrettyPrinter$$anonfun$safeDefault$2.apply(PrettyPrinters.scala:74)

at com.novus.salat.util.GraterPrettyPrinter$$anonfun$safeDefault$2.apply(PrettyPrinters.scala:74)

at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:147)

at com.novus.salat.util.GraterPrettyPrinter$class.safeDefault(PrettyPrinters.scala:74)

at com.novus.salat.util.ConstructorInputPrettyPrinter$.safeDefault(PrettyPrinters.scala:108)

at com.novus.salat.util.ConstructorInputPrettyPrinter$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PrettyPrinters.scala:134)

at com.novus.salat.util.ConstructorInputPrettyPrinter$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PrettyPrinters.scala:128)

at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:34)

at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:38)

at com.novus.salat.util.ConstructorInputPrettyPrinter$.apply(PrettyPrinters.scala:128)

at com.novus.salat.util.ToObjectGlitch.<init>(ToObjectGlitch.scala:44)

at com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater.feedArgsToConstructor(Grater.scala:294)

at com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater.asObject(Grater.scala:263)

at com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater.asObject(Grater.scala:105)

at com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursorBase$class.next(SalatMongoCursor.scala:47)

at com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursor.next(SalatMongoCursor.scala:149)

at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:652)

at com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursor.foreach(SalatMongoCursor.scala:149)

at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)

at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:128)

at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:242)

at com.novus.salat.dao.SalatMongoCursor.toList(SalatMongoCursor.scala:149)
```

Comment: Post your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve And a complete stacktrace or at least indicate where in your code you get the exception

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to corrupt data in the db. After clearing that it worked.